# Looping a python command from bash, cannot use floats as parameter for command

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, loops, floating-point

I am trying to loop a python command in my bash terminal to take many float values for a certain parameter.

This is what I have so far:

```
for ((t=0; t <= 165; t=t+5));
   do python3 filename 1 [echo $t/100] 0;
   done
```

I want to loop over values between 0 and 1.65, on .05 increments. Only bash doesn't seem to accept float values like that, and the echo command is not being recognized by python. I have gotten errors like "cannot convert [echo to a float", or that ( is not correct syntax if I replace the square brackets.

What can I do to fix this? the ideal situation would be for my script to run:

```
python3 filename 1 0.00 0
python3 filename 1 0.05 0
.
.
.
python3 filename 1 1.65 0
```

each after the other without them running simultaneously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With bash version 4.0+, you can use a brace expansion and string manipulation to formulate that float number:

```sh
for n in {000..165..5}; do
  echo python3 filename 1 "${n%??}.${n#?}" 0
done
```

`${n%??}` removes 2 chars from the end of the string,
`${n#?}` removes 1 char from the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest without a lot of fuzz is to make use of the sequence command `seq`. This command allows you to make a sequence of numbers with any increment:

```
seq FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

In the case of the OP, there is a request to generate the numbers 0.00 0.05 0.10 ... 1.65, so all that needs to be done is

```
for x in $(seq 0 0.05 1.65); do
  python3 filename 1 "$x" 0
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Performing the loop within `bc`,
Formatting number with bash,
Calling the script with `xargs`:

```sh
LC_NUMERIC=C printf '%0.2f\n' \
  $(<<<'scale=2;i=0;while(i<=1.65){i;i+=.05}' bc) |
    xargs -l -I{} python3 filename 1 {} 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash` doesn't do floating-point arithmetic. Use an external command like `bc`.

```
for ((t=0; t <= 165; t=t+5));
   do python3 filename 1 "$(echo "scale=2; $t / 100" | bc)" 0
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the division in the python script and just pass whole numbers instead.